# Where is the heatmap tool in QGIS 3.0?

Tags: qgis-3

I cannot find the heatmap tool in QGIS 3.0.  I read that it has been moved from "Raster" to "Processing" but I cannot find it in processing either.

Update:
I do not see "Interpolation" under "processing"

[image]

Comment: Ctr+K works for me to find Heatmap in QGIS 3.0.1 on Windows.  Actually I see that Processing > Toolbox > Interpolation also finds it

Comment: Some of my students are missing the heatmap tool on their programms. Assuming there has been a new update which will not show the heatmap in the search bar. Any ideas how to add it to QGIS 3.4 for those students?

Comment: @FrigoDe Have you checked the solutions people have offered in this thread? Have you tried finding it in the processing toolbox? Is the processing toolbox turned on?

Comment: Thanks, will try this one out. All students (44) downloaded QGIS at about the same time and about 8% are missing the heatmap function when using search function ctrl + K. Will try out, if there is an easy way to turn the processing toolbox on.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/157010)

Answer (score 10):

The Heatmap tool is in `Processing menu > Toolbox > Interpolation`. You can also find it using the locator toolbar (Ctrl+K).

Yet I saw a case similar to yours with one of our students, when the exact tool simply couldn't be found. The solution in that particular case was to go the Manage and Install Plugins dialog, to uncheck and the check again *Processing* from the Installed Plugins. It then appeared as expected.

Answer (score 2):

[@Linwoodc3's comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/282352/where-is-the-heatmap-tool-in-qgis-3-0/322346#comment492907_297436) explains how to use the built in heatmap tool:

> [It] is correct that the Heatmap Plugin is gone from QGIS 3, but  the
>   Heatmap tool is still available for use.  In the search bar in the
>   bottom left corner of QGIS, just type "Heatmap" and you will see the
>   built in function.
>
> Here is a video tutorial on using the Heatmap in QGIS 3.0:
>   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9Gqrr5cYrY

This question may be old now, but I've not seen the correct response anywhere yet.

Assuming you're referring to the Heatmap Plugin that uses KDEs to produce heatmaps (https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_heatmap.html), the reason you can't find it in QGIS 3.0 is because it's not available yet for this version. It is available for QGIS 2.18.0, and you can install it from the Plugins menu. It is not available to install from the 3.0 Plugins menu.